# How can I fix "expected '{' as first char" in my testfor command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you use the `testfor` command to detect if a player has a certain score?!

I tried,

```
/testfor @a [score_A_min=10]
```

but it says, "expected '{' as first char".

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**, you have an extra space where none should be

```
/testfor @a[score_A_min=10]
```

**Long answer**, the syntax for `testfor` is

```
/testfor <player> [dataTag]
```

where `<player>` is required and `[dataTag]` is optional. More importantly `dataTag` is *not* the target selector argument (which you are trying to use), but a compound NBT tag, which is indeed contained in `{}`, e.g. `{XpLevel:3}`.

The target selector argument has to follow the target selector immediately without a space in between, like this

```
@<variable>[<argument>=<value>,<argument>=<value>,…].
```